# Woocommerce/WordPress BarclayCard Payment Gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate BarclayCard with a wordpress website. The issue is that everything happens fine/ It's just that on the return URL (notify_url), the redirection from BarclayCard to the website fails unless I use a custom page URL in the notify_url field. Also, I need to go into the woocommerce admin portal to manually send the customer details. The order status is stuck on 'pending payment' and I have to manually check the barclaycard portal to confirm the payment and then change the payment status to 'complete' on the woocommerce admin portal.

The problem lies when the payment result is redirected back to the website from the barclaycard payment page. Can you please tell me what I need to do so that payment result is correctly transmitted and the customer is redirected to the default woocommerce order confirmation page?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

class RapidDive_WC_Gateway_Barclay extends WC_Payment_Gateway
{
    const TEST_URL = 'https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp';
    const LIVE_URL = 'https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/orderstandard.asp';

    public static $log_enabled = false;

    public static $log = false;
    protected $access_key;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 'barclay';
        $this->method_title = __('Barclay ePDQ', 'woocommerce');
        $this->order_button_text = __('Proceed to Barcalay ePDQ', 'woocommerce');
        $this->method_description = __('Barclay ePDQ redirects customers to Barclay to enter their payment information.',
            'woocommerce');
        $this->supports = array(
            'products',
//            'refunds',
        );
        $this->icon = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../assets/barclaycard_logo.png';

        // Load the settings.
        $this->init_form_fields();
        $this->init_settings();

        $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
        $this->title = ($this->title !== null && $this->title !== '') ? $this->title : __('Barclay ePDQ', 'woocommerce');
        $this->description = $this->get_option('description');
        $this->access_key = $this->get_option('access_key');
        $this->showLogo = $this->get_option('show_logo');

        $this->status = $this->get_option('status');
        $this->error_notice = $this->get_option('error_notice');
        $this->sha_in = $this->get_option('sha_in');
        $this->sha_out = $this->get_option('sha_out');
        $this->sha_method = $this->get_option('sha_method');
        $this->sha_method = ($this->sha_method != '') ? $this->sha_method : 0;

        $this->cat_url = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');

        $this->aavscheck = $this->get_option('aavcheck');
        $this->cvccheck = $this->get_option('cvccheck');

        $this->payment_method = is_array($this->get_option('payment_method')) ? implode(';',
            $this->get_option('payment_method')) : '';
        $this->brand_cards = is_array($this->get_option('brand_cards')) ? implode(';',
            $this->get_option('brand_cards')) : '';
        $this->secure_3d = $this->get_option('secure_3d');
//        $this->method_list = $this->get_option('method_list');
        $this->method_list = is_array($this->get_option('method_list')) ? implode(';',
            $this->get_option('method_list')) : '';

        $this->com_plus = $this->get_option('com_plus');
        $this->param_plus = $this->get_option('param_plus');

        $this->param_var = $this->get_option('param_var');

        //Recommended for Direct Payments and Advanced Payments
        $this->operation = $this->get_option('operation');
        $this->api_user_id = $this->get_option('api_user_id');
        $this->api_user_pswd = $this->get_option('api_user_pswd');


        //Recommended for Direct Payments and Advanced Payments
        $this->operation = $this->get_option('operation');
        $this->api_user_id = $this->get_option('api_user_id');
        $this->api_user_pswd = $this->get_option('api_user_pswd');

        $this->notify_url = 'https://www.example.com/custom-page-url/';

        // templating
        $this->pp_format = $this->get_option('pp_format ');
        $this->TITLE = $this->get_option('TITLE');
        $this->BGCOLOR = $this->get_option('BGCOLOR');
        $this->TXTCOLOR = $this->get_option('TXTCOLOR');
        $this->TBLBGCOLOR = $this->get_option('TBLBGCOLOR');
        $this->TBLTXTCOLOR = $this->get_option('TBLTXTCOLOR');
        $this->BUTTONBGCOLOR = $this->get_option('BUTTONBGCOLOR');
        $this->BUTTONTXTCOLOR = $this->get_option('BUTTONTXTCOLOR');
        $this->FONTTYPE = $this->get_option('FONTTYPE');
        $this->LOGO = $this->get_option('LOGO');

        $this->add_payment_hooks();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
     */
    public function init_form_fields()
    {
        $this->form_fields = include('includes/settings-barclay.php');
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private function add_payment_hooks()
    {
        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
        add_action('woocommerce_receipt_barclay', array($this, 'receipt_page'));
        add_action('woocommerce_api_rapiddive_wc_gateway_barclay', array($this, 'check_barclay_response'));
    }

    /**
     * @param $message
     * @param string $level
     */
    public static function log($message, $level = 'info')
    {
        if (self::$log_enabled) {
            if (self::$log === null) {
                self::$log = wc_get_logger();
            }
            self::$log->log($level, $message, array('source' => 'barclay'));
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function admin_options()
    {
        ?>
        <h2> <?php _e('Barclay Payment Gateway', 'woocommerce'); ?> </h2>
        <table class="form-table">
            <?php $this->generate_settings_html(); ?>
        </table> <?php
    }

    /**
     * @param int $order_id
     * @return array
     */
    public function process_payment($order_id)
    {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        return array(
            'result' => 'success',
            'redirect' => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(true)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param $order
     */
    public function receipt_page($order)
    {
        echo '<p>' . __('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with Barclay ePDQ.',
                'woocommerce') . '</p>';
        echo $this->generate_barclay_form($order);
    }

    /**
     * @param $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function generate_barclay_form($order)
    {
        $order = wc_get_order($order);
        $barclay_args = $this->get_barclay_fields($order);

        $shasign = '';
        $shasign_arg = array();

        ksort($barclay_args);
        foreach ($barclay_args as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == '') {
                continue;
            }
            $shasign_arg[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }

        if ($this->sha_method == 0) {
            $shasign = sha1(implode($this->sha_in, $shasign_arg) . $this->sha_in);
        } elseif ($this->sha_method == 1) {
            $shasign = hash('sha256', implode($this->sha_in, $shasign_arg) . $this->sha_in);
        } elseif ($this->sha_method == 2) {
            $shasign = hash('sha512', implode($this->sha_in, $shasign_arg) . $this->sha_in);
        }

        $barclay_html_args = array();
        foreach ($barclay_args as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == '') {
                continue;
            }
            $barclay_html_args[] = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '"/>';
        }

        if (isset($this->status) && ($this->status == 'test' || $this->status == 'live')) {
            $url = $this->status == 'test' ? self::TEST_URL : self::LIVE_URL;

            return
                '<form action="' . esc_url($url) . '" method="post" id="epdq_payment_form">' .
                implode('', $barclay_html_args) .
                '<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="' . $shasign . '"/>' .
                '<input type="submit" class="button alt" id="submit_epdq_payment_form" value="' . __('Pay via Barclay ePDQ',
                    'woocommerce') . '" />' .
                '<a class="button cancel" href="' . esc_url($order->get_cancel_order_url()) . '">' . __('Cancel order &amp; restore cart',
                    'woocommerce') . '</a>' .
                '</form>';
        } else {
            return '<p class="error">' . $this->error_notice . '</p>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $order_id
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_barclay_fields($order_id)
    {

        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        // var_dump(get_class_methods($order));
        // exit;
        $barclay_args = array(
            'PSPID' => $this->access_key,
            'ORDERID' => $order->id,
            'AMOUNT' => $order->order_total * 100,
            'CURRENCY' => get_woocommerce_currency(),
            'LANGUAGE' => get_bloginfo('language'),
            'CN' => $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name,
            'EMAIL' => $order->billing_email,
            'OWNERZIP' => $order->billing_postcode,
            'OWNERADDRESS' => $order->billing_address_1,
            'OWNERADDRESS2' => $order->billing_address_2,
            'OWNERCTY' => $order->billing_country,
            'OWNERTOWN' => $order->billing_city,
            'OWNERTELNO' => $order->billing_phone,

            'ACCEPTURL' => $this->notify_url,
            'DECLINEURL' => $this->notify_url,
            'EXCEPTIONURL' => $this->notify_url,
            // 'CANCELURL' => $this->notify_url,
            'CANCELURL' => esc_url_raw($order->get_cancel_order_url_raw()),
            'BACKURL' => '',
            'HOMEURL' => '',
            'CATALOGURL' => get_permalink($this->cat_url),

            //payment method
            'PM' => $this->payment_method,
            'BRAND' => $this->brand_cards,
            'WIN3DS' => $this->secure_3d,
            'PMLISTTYPE' => $this->method_list,

            //Redirection on payment result
            'COMPLUS' => $this->com_plus,
            'PARAMPLUS' => $this->param_plus,

            //POST payment url
            'PARAMVAR' => $this->param_var,

            //REcommended for direct payments
            'OPERATION' => $this->operation,
            'USERID' => $this->api_user_id,
            'PASWD' => $this->api_user_pswd
        );

        if ($this->pp_format == 'yes') {
            $barclay_args['TITLE'] = $this->TITLE;
            $barclay_args['BGCOLOR'] = $this->BGCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['TXTCOLOR'] = $this->TXTCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['TBLBGCOLOR'] = $this->TBLBGCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['TBLTXTCOLOR'] = $this->TBLTXTCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['BUTTONBGCOLOR'] = $this->BUTTONBGCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['BUTTONTXTCOLOR'] = $this->BUTTONTXTCOLOR;
            $barclay_args['FONTTYPE'] = $this->FONTTYPE;
            $barclay_args['LOGO'] = $this->LOGO;
        }
        return $barclay_args;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function payment_fields()
    {
        if ($this->showLogo === 'yes') {
            echo '<img src="' . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../assets/epdq.gif"/>';
        }
        if ($description = $this->get_description()) {
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($description));
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    function check_barclay_response()
    {
        ob_clean();
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

        $datacheck = array();
        $datacheck1 = array();

        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == "") {
                continue;
            }
            $datacheck[$key] = $value;
            $datacheck1[strtoupper($key)] = strtoupper($value);
        }

        $verify = $this->checkShaOut($datacheck);

        if ($verify) {
            $this->transaction_successfull($datacheck1);
        } else {
            wp_die('Transaction is unsuccessfull!');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $datacheck
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function checkShaOut($datacheck)
    {
        $shaout = $this->sha_out;

        $origsig = $datacheck['SHASIGN'];

        unset($datacheck['SHASIGN']);
        unset($datacheck['wc-api']);

        uksort($datacheck, 'strcasecmp');
        $shasign = "";

        $shasig = null;
        foreach ($datacheck as $key => $value) {
            $shasig .= trim(strtoupper($key)) . '=' . utf8_encode(trim($value)) . $shaout;
        }

        $shasig = strtoupper(hash('sha1', $shasig));

        if ($shasig == $origsig) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $args
     */
    function transaction_successfull($args)
    {
        global $woocommerce;

        extract($args);
        $order = new WC_Order($ORDERID);

        $accepted = array(4, 5, 9, 41, 51, 91);
        $status = $STATUS;
        $ncerror = $NCERROR;

        $dienote = '<p>Transection result is uncertain.<p>';
        $dienote .= '<p>Status Code: ' . $STATUS . ' - ' . $this->get_barclay_status_code($status) . '';
        $dienote .= '<br>Error Code: ' . $NCERROR . ' - ' . $this->get_barclay_ncerror($ncerror) . '</p>';
        $died = '';
        $died .= $dienote;
        $died .= '<p>Your order is cancelled and your cart is emptied.';
        $died .= '<br>Go to your <a href="' . get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) . '">account</a> to process your order again or ';
        $died .= 'go to <a href="' . home_url() . '">homepage</a></p>';

        if (in_array($STATUS, $accepted)) {

            if (!empty($args['ORDERID'])) {
                $note = 'Order ID: ' . $ORDERID . '.<br>';
            } //    order id
            if (!empty($args['AMOUNT'])) {
                $note .= 'Amount: ' . $AMOUNT . '.<br>';
            } //    amount
            if (!empty($args['CURRENCY'])) {
                $note .= 'Order currency: ' . $CURRENCY . '.<br>';
            } //    order currency
            if (!empty($args['PM'])) {
                $note .= 'Payment Method: ' . $PM . '.<br>';
            } //    payment method
            if (!empty($args['ACCEPTANCE'])) {
                $note .= 'Acceptance code returned by acquirer: ' . $ACCEPTANCE . '.<br>';
            }    // acceptance
            if (!empty($args['STATUS'])) {
                $note .= 'Transaction status : ' . $STATUS . '.<br>';
            } //    status code
            if (!empty($args['CARDNO'])) {
                $note .= 'Masked card number : ' . $CARDNO . '.<br>';
            } //    catd no
            if (!empty($args['PAYID'])) {
                $note .= 'Payment reference in EPDQ system: ' . $PAYID . '.<br>';
            } //    pay id
            if (!empty($args['NCERROR'])) {
                $note .= 'Error Code: ' . $NCERROR . '.<br>';
            } //    ncerror
            if (!empty($args['BRAND'])) {
                $note .= 'Card brand (EPDQ system derives this from the card number) : ' . $BRAND . '.<br>';
            } //    brand
            if (!empty($args['ED'])) {
                $note .= 'Payer\'s card expiry date : ' . $ED . '.<br>';
            } //    expiry date
            if (!empty($args['TRXDATE'])) {
                $note .= 'Transaction Date: ' . $TRXDATE . '.<br>';
            } //    date
            if (!empty($args['CN'])) {
                $note .= 'Cardholder/customer name: ' . $CN . '.<br>';
            } //    payer's name
            if (!empty($args['IP'])) {
                $note .= 'Customer\'s IP: ' . $IP . '.<br>';
            } //    payer's ip


            if (!empty($args['AAVADDRESS'])) {
                $note .= 'AAV result for the address: ' . $AAVADDRESS . ' . <br>';
            } //    aav address
            if (!empty($args['AAVCHECK'])) {
                $note .= 'Result of the automatic address verification: ' . $AAVCHECK . ' . <br>';
            } //    aav check
            if (!empty($args['AAVZIP'])) {
                $note .= 'AAV result for the zip code: ' . $AAVZIP . ' . <br>';
            } // aav zip
            if (!empty($args['BIN'])) {
                $note .= 'First 6 digits of credit card number: ' . $BIN . ' . <br>';
            } // bin
            if (!empty($args['CCCTY'])) {
                $note .= 'Country where the card was issued: ' . $CCCTY . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['COMPLUS'])) {
                $note .= 'Custom value passed: ' . $COMPLUS . ' . <br>';
            }

            if (!empty($args['CVCCHECK'])) {
                $note .= 'Result of the card verification code check: ' . $CVCCHECK . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['ECI'])) {
                $note .= 'Electronic Commerce Indicator: ' . $ECI . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['FXAMOUNT'])) {
                $note .= 'FXAMOUNT: ' . $FXAMOUNT . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['FXCURRENCY'])) {
                $note .= 'FXCURRENCY: ' . $FXCURRENCY . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['IPCTY'])) {
                $note .= 'Originating country of the IP address: ' . $IPCTY . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['SUBBRAND'])) {
                $note .= 'SUBBRAND: ' . $SUBBRAND . ' . <br>';
            }
            if (!empty($args['VC'])) {
                $note .= 'Virtual Card type: ' . $SUBBRAND . ' . <br>';
            }


            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

            if (in_array($STATUS, array(4, 5, 9))) {
                $note = 'Barclay ePDQ transaction is confirmed.<br>';
                $note .= $note;
                $order->add_order_note($note);
                $order->payment_complete();
            }

            if (in_array($STATUS, array(41, 51, 91))) {
                $note = 'Barclay ePDQ transaction is awaiting for confirmation.<br>';
                $note .= $note;
                $order->update_status('on-hold', $note);
            }

        } elseif ($STATUS == 2 || $STATUS == 93) {
            $dienote .= '<br>Order is failed.';
            $order->update_status('failed', $dienote);
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        } elseif ($STATUS == 52 || $STATUS == 92) {
            $dienote .= '<br>Order is failed.';
            $order->update_status('failed', $dienote);
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        } elseif ($STATUS == 1) {
            $dienote .= '<br>Order is cancelled.';
            $order->update_status('cancelled', $dienote);
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        } else {
            $dienote .= '<br>Order is failed.';
            $order->update_status('failed', $dienote);
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        }

        wp_redirect($this->get_return_url($order));
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * @param $code
     * @return mixed|string|void
     */
    function get_barclay_status_code($code)
    {
        if ($code == '') {
            return;
        }
        $codes = array(
            0 => 'Incomplete or invalid',
            1 => 'Cancelled by client',
            2 => 'Authorisation refused',
            4 => 'Order stored',
            40 => 'Stored waiting external result',
            41 => 'Waiting client payment',
            5 => 'Authorised',
            51 => 'Authorisation waiting',
            52 => 'Authorisation not known',
            55 => 'Standby',
            56 => 'OK with scheduled payments',
            57 => 'Not OK with scheduled payments',
            59 => 'Author. to get manually',
            6 => 'Authorised and canceled',
            61 => 'Author. deletion waiting',
            62 => 'Author. deletion uncertain',
            63 => 'Author. deletion refused',
            64 => 'Authorised and cancelled',
            7 => 'Payment deleted',
            71 => 'Payment deletion pending',
            72 => 'Payment deletion uncertain',
            73 => 'Payment deletion refused',
            74 => 'Payment deleted (not accepted)',
            75 => 'Deletion processed by merchant',
            8 => 'Refund',
            81 => 'Refund pending',
            82 => 'Refund uncertain',
            83 => 'Refund refused',
            84 => 'Payment declined by the acquirer (will be debited)',
            85 => 'Refund processed by merchant',
            9 => 'Payment requested',
            91 => 'Payment processing',
            92 => 'Payment uncertain',
            93 => 'Payment refused',
            94 => 'Refund declined by the acquirer',
            95 => 'Payment processed by merchant',
            96 => 'Refund reversed',
            97 => 'Being processed - intermediate technical status',
            98 => 'Being processed - intermediate technical status',
            99 => 'Being processed - intermediate technical status'
        );
        if (isset($codes[$code])) {
            return $codes[$code];
        } else {
            return 'Unknown';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $code
     * @return mixed|string|void
     */
    function get_barclay_ncerror($code)
    {
        if ($code == '') {
            return;
        }

....
...
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/ajbrowe/woocommerce-epdq-payment-gateway - Is this the one?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. It leads me to 'transaction has failed' status so I need to modify the notify_url otherwise it doesn't send any parameters back to the website.

Comment: Have you tried any of these - $this->notify_url = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'WC_Nom_EPDQ', $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() ) );

$this->notify_url   = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'WC_Nom_EPDQ', get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('thanks')) ) );

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have used both of those. The first one gives the site 'a critical error' and the second one fails verification so BarclayCard rejects the request. Is there a way I can put it in the url? I used site_url().'/checkout/order-received/'.$order_id.'/'.$order_key; but I don't know how to get $order_key back in parameters from Barclaycard since that is generated by woocommerce. Really stuck here